# Yii2: REST POST request parameters not arriving to action

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I'm making a REST API using Yii2.
I enabled pretty URLs `via /config/web.php`

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        //'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => $routes,
]
```

This is the content of the $routes variable (basically just the contents of a php script that has my rules separate from the web.php config file):

```
return [
        '<controller:[\w\-]+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        'api/<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>/<id:\d+>' => 'api/<controller>/<action>',
        'api/<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>' => 'api/<controller>/<action>',
        'module/<module:[\w\-]+>/<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
        ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
         'controller' => [
            'api/x_controller',
            'api/y_controller',
            'api/z_controller'
            ],
         'pluralize' => false,
        ]
];
```

And it works fine except for the fact that I can't get any parameters I send (I'm aiming for JSON but have also tried to send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data and had the same results).
Current code that tries to get any kind of parameters from the request is:

```
public function actionDoSomething  
{
    $contentType = Yii::$app->request->getContentType();
    $raw = Yii::$app->request->getRawBody();
    $queryParams = Yii::$app->request->getQueryParams();
    $bodyParams = Yii::$app->request->getBodyParams();
    $token = Yii::$app->request->getBodyParam('access_token');
    $userID = Yii::$app->request->getBodyParam('user_id');
    $rawJson = file_get_contents("php://input");
}
```

Unfortunately all of those variables are either null or empty even though along with my POST request I send `{"access_token":"XXXtoken","userId":"60"}`.

I'm guessing it's something about my urlManager but I can't quite figure out what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the problem was not in Yii2 at all.
After checking our GoDaddy configuration we found our A Record was pointing to the wrong IP.
After pointing it to the correct IP the problem was solved.

To tell the truth, I wouldn't expect the request to arrive to the server at all with that part of the configuration being wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've used something like this in a middleware position to parse out various types of input at once.

```
//Store the various HTTP methods to check against
$methods_to_check = array('POST', 'PUT');    

//Check if this request should be parsed
if(in_array(strtoupper(Yii::$app->request->getMethod()), $methods_to_check)){
    //Initialize the value to store data in
    $input = '';

    //Get reference to PHP's input
    $file_handle = fopen('php://input', 'r');

    //Loop through PHP's input until end of stream is reached
    while(!feof($file_handle)){
        $s = fread($file_handle, 64);

        $input .= $s;
    }

    //Close reference to PHP's input
    fclose($file_handle);

    //Check if any data was passed, and merge the JSON-decoded version of it into the $_POST array
    if(!empty($input)) $_POST = array_merge($_POST, (array)json_decode($input));
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this can aid me in my problem, really.
Also, tested some of it and the Yii::$app() threw an error.

Comment: Sorry, your right, hasty 1.1 -> 2.0 conversion. So, you're saying that reading in from that php input isn't displaying any data? Does it work if you use multi-part data instead? How are you sending the data to the server?